# Ubuntu Kickstart installation using LVM waits for input

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, automation, kickstart, preseed

I have a PXE Boot Setup for installing CentOS 5 and Ubuntu 10.04 via Kickstart. I use LVM and installing CentOS without any user interaction works but Ubuntu always asks to "confirm to write changes to disk and configure LVM" during partitioning. If I don't use LVM, Ubuntu will not ask for any confirmation and just partitions the disk.

The part of the kickstart file where I handle the partitions looks like this:

```
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
#Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype ext2 --size 200 --asprimary
part swap  --size 1024
part pv.01 --size 1 --grow
volgroup rootvg pv.01
logvol / --fstype ext4 --vgname=rootvg --size=1 --grow --name=rootvol
```

How can I tell Ubuntu to always accept the settings without selecting "yes" on the screen? Is there something like a `confirm all` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to my problem, you have to use the preseed option to confirm the LVM question. Just add the following line to the Kickstart file.

```
preseed partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Comment: does the location of the placement matters? i have added the command but still getting the confirmation prompt.

Comment: can you provide example?

Answer (score 1):

In the file ks.cfg

```
preseed partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
preseed partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
preseed partman/confirm boolean true
preseed partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```