# Debian preseed prompts disk select dispite it being seeded

Tags: debian, preseed, debian-stretch

In our environment we are automating deployment of Debian VMs to run workloads.
Everything in our preseed file works except for the selection of the disk.
This still gets prompted.

Our preseed config for disks is:

```
 d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free
 d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
 d-i partman-auto/method regular
 d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

 d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
 d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
 d-i partman/confirm boolean true
 d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

despite this, we still get prompted by the disk select:
[image: Debian installer select disk prompt]

As you can see, the correct disk is sda...
(I checked many recipes and there didn't seem to be, this is the standard command from the debian project itself)

Comment: `d-i partman-auto/method string regular`  instead of  `d-i partman-auto/method regular` maybe?

Comment: Also look at https://serverfault.com/questions/415174/debian-6-preseeding-keeps-asking-write-the-changes-to-disks-and-configure-lvm

Comment: Well I'll eat my hat, it was "string" that was missing.
Because it locked on disk select I thought it was that line that was off, but it was the next line that was off. Put it up as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been discovered, you are missing a `string` token.

So use:

`d-i partman-auto/method string regular`

instead of your current:

`d-i partman-auto/method regular`